# Parsing a JSON array with Json.Net

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a json that looks like this:

```
"events": {
  "Arsenal_West Ham United": {
    "sport": "EPL",
    "sport_display": "EPL",
    "participants": [
      "Arsenal",
      "West Ham United"
    ],
    "home_team": "Arsenal",
    "commence": "1524400200",
    "status": "Pending",
    "sites": {
      "williamhill": {
        "odds": {
          "h2h": [
            "1.50",
            "6.50",
            "4.50"
          ]
        },
        "last_update": 1524385803
      }
    }
  }
 }
```

While I have managed to read much of the data provided, I have fatigued to read the data from the "sites" by using the following.

```
var sites = match.Value["sites"];

                foreach(var site in sites)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(site);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
```

but this returns

```
"williamhill": {
        "odds": {
          "h2h": [
            "1.50",
            "6.50",
            "4.50"
          ]
        },
        "last_update": 1524385803
      }
```

I want to read every item in sites individually, meaning that for example I want to store "williamhill" in a string and get each bet individually.

Comment: Could you please develop a little bit more your explanation on how do you intend to group the results in your C# code?

Comment: have you tried using [Json.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)?

Comment: I am going to the data in a database depending on the value of the data. For example odds will be saved in a db depending on direction of the bet, the data in "last_update" will be stored to check the time the data was last updated and so on

Comment: The `sites`  property of your JSON is not an array, is more like a `Dictionary<string, SomeObject>`. You should really try to deserialize your JSON to a strongly typed object, that's what JSON.NET is for.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma I have been able to read everything so far, its just the sites that Im having a problem with :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*sites* gave you one result because it has one result of type *williamhill*

*williamhill* will also give you one result of type *odds* (you get the idea)

if you look at your json in a class perspective you will see something like that

```
public class Odds
{
    public List<string> h2h { get; set; }
}

public class Williamhill
{
    public Odds odds { get; set; }
    public int last_update { get; set; }
}

public class Sites
{
    public Williamhill williamhill { get; set; }
}
//here the root object is the sites but ofcourse the real root object is events
public class RootObject
{
    public Sites sites { get; set; }
}

string json = // yourJson
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);

var h2h = obj["events"]["Arsenal_West Ham United"]["sites"]["williamhill"]["odds"]["h2h"];
foreach (var item in h2h)
{
   Debug.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Edit, to view the betting companies

```
  JToken sites = obj["events"]["Arsenal_West Ham United"]["sites"];

  foreach (JProperty content in sites)
  {
      Debug.WriteLine(content.Name);

   }
```

output

> williamhill

Comment: Is there any way to access the betting company name dynamically instead of hard coding it ? as I have more than one company name